# Is there a way to switch the connection to another TCP server?

Tags: node.js

I have made my personal project using WebSocket.

I already know that WebSocket will not connect directly raw TCP Socket.

so, I have thought what if I connect, at first, to Web Server(NodeJS) and then switch to TCP server.

is It possible to switch connection to another server using NodeJS?

If so.

Please let me happy.. Thank you! have a nice day.

Comment: What are you asking?  You have a WebSockets client connected to a Node.js server, and you want to then connect the client to a completely different server, or the same server different port?  What?

Comment: After the initial HTTP handshake and Upgrade header, a websocket connection IS a raw TCP connection.

Comment: @Brand
Yes! I want to switch client connection to a completely different TCP server, not HTTP Server,

Comment: @PeterLyons
I have heard WebSocket is completely not a raw TCP connection.

Comment: Have you tried reading some authoritative material? It's called a WebSocket because it starts out as a web transaction (HTTP over TCP) and results in a socket (raw TCP). I think this comes down to a "hear me now, believe me later" type situation. :-)

Comment: I had researched many website including wiki, w3c spec and so on, but I saw that WebSocket is built-on TCP but It is just a TCP-like, bi-direction connection

Comment: If I'm not, Please let me know. where right answer is.

Comment: Thanks @Peter Lyons
I already know that my english expression is very poor, :-(

Answer (score 1):

I would assume it might be both possible and straightforward to tunnel/proxy TCP traffic. The high level design would be:

- Start up a web server with integrated websocket server (use socket.io, really)
- When a client makes a websocket connection, create an upstream TCP connection to your target server
- Then do full bidirectional piping of messages between the browser<->node socket and the node<->otherServer socket

Devil might be in the details. I haven't tried, but seems feasible.

There's a [node project called ws-tcp-bridge](https://github.com/andrewchambers/ws-tcp-bridge) as well as a [python project](https://github.com/iuridiniz/stupid-websocket-tcp-proxy) that claim to do this already. Neither luke terribly mature, but they might just work or at least provide good reference material.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I think It also  would be a good solution, 
However if there is another way, I want to take it,
really Is not there complete solution for this question?